# ConnectionException trying to connect to mongoDB in docker from another docker container using docker-compose

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to connect to mongoDB in a container from a service in another container but getting connection exceptions

I have created a docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
  mongo-container:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongo-container"
    environment:
      - MONGO_INITDB_DATABASE=transactions

    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - banking-network
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db

  transaction-service:
    image: transaction-service
    container_name: transaction-service
    build:
      context: transaction-service
      dockerfile: local.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    depends_on:
      - mongo-container
    environment:
      - MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo-container:27017/transactions
    networks:
      - banking-network
networks:
  banking-network:
    external:
      name: banking-network

volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
```

And in my service application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: transaction-service
server:
  port: '8083'

mongodb:
  connection:
    string: mongodb://mongo-container:27017/transactions
  database: transactions
```

So I have a service in one container, and mongoDb in another, both on the same network

```
d666b7a242fc   transaction-service   "java -jar /app/tran…"   18 minutes ago   Up 18 minutes   0.0.0.0:8083->8083/tcp     transaction-service
516d539b29c7   mongo:latest          "docker-entrypoint.s…"   18 minutes ago   Up 18 minutes   0.0.0.0:27017->27017/tcp   mongo-container
```

The following is MONGO_URL=mongodb://name of container:27017/name of database

```
- MONGO_URL=mongodb://mongo-container:27017/transactions
```

Now I can connect to this mongodb from a rest service running on my local host without needing a password and username so I have not added it to my docker-compose. I have seen other examples not using it.

But I am still getting an exception.

It seems this should be straightforward, it has the docker container name, the port and its on the same network. What am I missing.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found wiring up that does allow one container to talk to another.
The confusing thing, is its totally different to how the docs say to do it
.

in my application.yml I have

```
spring:
  application:
    name: transaction-service
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: Transaction
      host: mongo-container
      port: 27017
server:
  port: '8083'
```

And in my docker-compose

```
services:
  mongo-container:
    image: mongo:latest
    container_name: "mongo-container"

    ports:
      - 27017:27017
    networks:
      - banking-network
    volumes:
      - mongodb_data_container:/data/db

  transaction-service:
    image: transaction-service
    container_name: transaction-service
    build:
      context: transaction-service
      dockerfile: local.dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8083:8083"
    depends_on:
      - mongo-container
    links:
      - mongo-container
    networks:
      - banking-network
networks:
  banking-network:
    external:
      name: banking-network

volumes:
  mongodb_data_container:
```

Its confusing that, what should work, what the documents detail does not work.
But this does.